# App is slowing down [General]

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, broadcastreceiver, android-wake-lock

I do have a more general question, without any specific code. I will explain what my application does and how and what issues I can monitor. Maybe one of you had the same issues and can lead me to the problem.

The App:

It reads car diagnostic data (OnBoardDiagnostics) over `Bluetooth` and shows them in real-time in a `ListView`. I can start the update function by a "update Button".

How:

Everytime a new value is received via `Bluetooth`, a background Class (which handles the `String`forming) sends an `Intent`to notify the UI to update the ListView.
The `Adapter` Class of my ListView has the listening `BroadcastReceiver` registered and if it gets triggered, it will notify the `ListView` by `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Issues:

1.If I use an `WakeLock` to keep the screen on, the UI refreshing slows down after approx. 10 minutes.

2.If I press the power button, so the screen is off, it still slows down (I can see that, because I send the values to an webserver) but furthermore: If I turn the screen back on. I see the `ListView` stops for about 20-30 seconds and than normally continues with normal speed (not slow anymore).

So.. I think this is a very general question. I searched for `WakeLock` and sleep behaviour, but I couldn't find any similar issues. Maybe one of you can give me a hint, what the problem could be. Maybe one of you had a similar problem.

Any hint is appreciated!

EDIT 1:

Maybe the problem of the 2. issue is based on the lifecycles of my objects / activity.
If I press the update Button, an `AsyncTask` is started, which sends the Data (JSON, which contains one new value for all list items) to my Webserver. If the device screen is off, I still get the data every 2 seconds. If I turn on the screen, it stops for these 20-30 seconds as well as the UI. So I think my UI works fine. The Update Intents were sent right.

I have to check if I still receive new values in that background class, mentioned above.
Thanks to [zapl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995891/zapl)

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is slowing down? The list scrolls slow, the broadcast receiver not receiving as many events or something else?

Comment: The list scrolling is fine. It's more like my whole app pauses. Ne values in the `ListView` are not updated. It's like no refresh Intent is sent. It's hard to debug, because I need to be in the car for about 10 minutes. I hoped someone could hint where I have to look.

Comment: Wakelocks do not slow down a device, they just prevent sleep. And your main activity is fine as long as the ui works smoothly all the time. If it is freezing/stuttering that would mean something is blocking in the ui thread. What you see is maybe normal behavior for the car / diagnostics adapter. I.e. it goes into slow mode after 10 minutes. When turning off the screen, maybe bluetooth disconnects and when you turn it back on it reconnects (which takes 20-30 seconds?) and then it starts from scratch. Do you have any comparable app / device that behaves differently?

Comment: First thanks for those suggestions! BT is always connected, that can not be the problem. I get valid data all the time on the webserver. Without any connection I would get nothing / no changing values. But the hint with the reconnect got me thinking about my App lifecycle. I will edit my Question to precise what I meant by that.

Comment: You could be generating a huge number of objects, which is causing a lot of garbage collection. You wouldn't see this immediately when you start your app, but after it has been running for awhile. If you look in the logcat you should be able to see the garbage collector activity (if you aren't filtering the logcat).

Comment: Another possibility is that you are doing a lot of work on the main (UI) thread is certain situations, which will make the app seem less responsive to UI events (scrolling, touches, etc.)

Comment: It is quite possible that i'm creating to many objects :D I'll have to check this, too. Thanks David!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except all possibilities I checked, i came across this article:

[AsyncTasks for long running Operations](http://simonvt.net/2014/04/17/asynctask-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/)

Short: There are some points you need to keep in mind if you are using AsyncTasks in very long running operations (>20min). My Problem was, that I used the AsyncTask as an inner Class. After a long period, when the Activity that created the Task was destroyed, the AsyncTask still kept a reference of this activity.

After I used a Bus, described in the article above, the UI worked fine!!

So, if anyone else noticed performance problems of your App, I recommend that article.

Thanks for all the other hints!
Have fun coding!